# Form is not displayed on panel admin Magento 2

Tags: magento-2.1, adminhtml, admin-panel

I want to add a form to my admin panel.

> app/code/Maxime/Jobs/Block/Adminhtml/Department/Edit.php

```
<?php
namespace Maxime\Jobs\Block\Adminhtml\Department;

use Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Form\Container;

class Edit extends Container
{
    /**
     * Core registry
     *
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Registry
     */
    protected $_coreRegistry = null;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_coreRegistry = $registry;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    /**
     * Department edit block
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_objectId = 'entity_id';
        $this->_blockGroup = 'Maxime_Jobs';
        $this->_controller = 'adminhtml_department';

        parent::_construct();

        if ($this->_isAllowedAction('Maxime_Jobs::department_save')) {
            $this->buttonList->update('save', 'label', __('Save Department'));
            $this->buttonList->add(
                'saveandcontinue',
                [
                    'label' => __('Save and Continue Edit'),
                    'class' => 'save',
                    'data_attribute' => [
                        'mage-init' => [
                            'button' => ['event' => 'saveAndContinueEdit', 'target' => '#edit_form'],
                        ],
                    ]
                ],
                -100
            );
        } else {
            $this->buttonList->remove('save');
        }

    }

    /**
     * Get header with Department name
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Phrase
     */
    public function getHeaderText()
    {
        if ($this->_coreRegistry->registry('jobs_department')->getId()) {
            return __("Edit Department '%1'", $this->escapeHtml($this->_coreRegistry->registry('jobs_department')->getName()));
        } else {
            return __('New Department');
        }
    }

    /**
     * Check permission for passed action
     *
     * @param string $resourceId
     * @return bool
     */
    protected function _isAllowedAction($resourceId)
    {
        return $this->_authorization->isAllowed($resourceId);
    }

    /**
     * Getter of url for "Save and Continue" button
     * tab_id will be replaced by desired by JS later
     *
     * @return string
     */
    protected function _getSaveAndContinueUrl()
    {
        return $this->getUrl('jobs/*/save', ['_current' => true, 'back' => 'edit', 'active_tab' => '']);
    }
}
```

> app/code/Maxime/Jobs/Block/Adminhtml/Department/Edit/Form.php

```
<?php
namespace Maxime\Jobs\Block\Adminhtml\Department\Edit;

use \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Form\Generic;

class Form extends Generic
{

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Store\Model\System\Store
     */
    protected $_systemStore;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Data\FormFactory $formFactory
     * @param \Magento\Store\Model\System\Store $systemStore
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        \Magento\Framework\Data\FormFactory $formFactory,
        \Magento\Store\Model\System\Store $systemStore,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_systemStore = $systemStore;
        parent::__construct($context, $registry, $formFactory, $data);
    }

    /**
     * Init form
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function _construct()
    {
        parent::_construct();
        $this->setId('department_form');
        $this->setTitle(__('Department Information'));
    }

    /**
     * Prepare form
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    protected function _prepareForm()
    {
        /** @var \Maxime\Jobs\Model\Department $model */
        $model = $this->_coreRegistry->registry('jobs_department');

        /** @var \Magento\Framework\Data\Form $form */
        $form = $this->_formFactory->create(
            ['data' => ['id' => 'edit_form', 'action' => $this->getData('action'), 'method' => 'post']]
        );

        $form->setHtmlIdPrefix('department_');

        $fieldset = $form->addFieldset(
            'base_fieldset',
            ['legend' => __('General Information'), 'class' => 'fieldset-wide']
        );

        if ($model->getId()) {
            $fieldset->addField('entity_id', 'hidden', ['name' => 'entity_id']);
        }

        $fieldset->addField(
            'name',
            'text',
            ['name' => 'name', 'label' => __('Department Name'), 'title' => __('Department Name'), 'required' => true]
        );

        $fieldset->addField(
            'description',
            'textarea',
            ['name' => 'description', 'label' => __('Department Description'), 'title' => __('Department Description'), 'required' => true]
        );

        $form->setValues($model->getData());
        $form->setUseContainer(true);
        $this->setForm($form);

        return parent::_prepareForm();
    }
}
```

Reference: https://www.maximehuran.fr/en/layouts-and-forms-on-magento-2-admin/

Now My form does not display
And in my system.log file I have this error

> main.CRITICAL: Block jobs_department_edit throws exception and cannot be rendered. [] []

How can I display my form?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Please change mode in to developer and check again, will find exact error on your custom module.

To check current mode :

```
magento deploy:mode:show
```

To change the current mode in to developer mode:

```
magento deploy:mode:set developer
```

Comment: 2 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException): Invalid block type: Maxime\Jobs\Block\Adminhtml\Department\Edit\Form
Exception #1 (ReflectionException): Class Maxime\Jobs\Block\Adminhtml\Department\Edit\Form does not exist